# Docker API v1.40 getting container logs

Tags: rest, docker, docker-api

I'm trying to retrieve container logs using Docker API.

Open API documentation of Docker states to get the container logs; syntax that should be used is;

> /containers/{id}/logs

According to documentation there could be three response statuses; **200**, **404** and **500**.

You can see the part of the documentation below;

```
responses:
        200:
          description: |
                  logs returned as a stream in response body.
                  For the stream format, [see the documentation for the attach endpoint](#operation/ContainerAttach).
                  Note that unlike the attach endpoint, the logs endpoint does not upgrade the connection and does not
                  set Content-Type.
          schema:
            type: "string"
            format: "binary"
        404:
          description: "no such container"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
          examples:
            application/json:
              message: "No such container: c2ada9df5af8"
        500:
          description: "server error"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

The interesting part for me is when I make a call I get 400 error which doesn't exist in the docs. 
Response message is like;

```
{
    "message": "Bad parameters: you must choose at least one stream"
}
```

How can I get the container logs using Docker API ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify where to return logs from by sending the `stdout` or `stderr` query parameters. Example:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/containerId/logs?stdout=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Docker API` in Python it can be done like that:

```py
import docker
from docker.models.containers import Container

image_id: str = "the_image_id_that_you_get_from_building"
container_object: Container = docker.from_env().containers.run(
    image_id,
    name="that-nice-name",
    detach=True,
)
for log_line in container_object.logs(stream=True):
    print(log_line.decode("utf-8"), end="")
```

The execution stops on the `for` loop - printing all the logs as they appear in the container. As soon as the container exits (is terminated for any reason) the execution leaves the `for` loop.